# Another Spring Security issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security for user authentication in my Spring MVC app. I discovered a very strange behavior which might be due to my bad configuration of Spring Security, or a bug. I need help finding out which one is it.

One important note, before anyone marks this question as a duplicate of some "Spring Security logout Back button"-like question: this problem has nothing to do with behavior after logging out. Everything here happens during one user session!

So, I have some pages that are visible to any user and some that are visible only to admin(s). `home.jsp` is visible to any user and it is `default-target-url` in my `spring-security.xml`. `users.jsp` page (list of all users) however is suppose to be visible only to admin.

Now a simple scenario:

1. Start the app
2. Log in as **user** and get redirected to `home.jsp` page any user can see
3. Navigate to page `users.jsp` only admin can see and get Access Denied (which is ok)
4. Navigate to any other page
5. Hit Back button and the `users.jsp` page appears and I can even see that admin is logged in, but I never logged in as admin since starting the app!!! (I can see who's logged in on every jsp page by using `<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />`)

This is my `spring-security.xml`:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/denied" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/list" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/{userId}/edit" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/delete" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <form-login login-page="/essays/auth/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/essays/auth/login?error=true"
                default-target-url="/essays/main/user/home"
                always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/essays/auth/denied"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/essays/auth/login"
            logout-url="/essays/auth/logout"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any ideas? Is this a bug or I'm doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Please start by clearing your cache. Then try again. If the problem persists, please attach the Spring Security logs for the entire flow you have specified.

Comment: Clearing the cache solved the problem. Now I just feel dumb. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RobWinch Please, make it an answer so I can accept it. Maybe it'll help someone else struggling to learn programming :)

Comment: @RobWinch This problem with cache, of course, happens again when I log in as admin and after that I log in as user again - which is logical, because I didn't clear the cache again. And I can't ask user to clear cache after every logout :) Is there a way to clear browsers cache programmatically? Or, better question would be - how to handle this problem? If you could please just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Configure your server to tell the browser not to cache pages. Here is [a useful guide to web caching](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). Also, you should usually use HTTPS in a secure application and tell users to close their browsers when they log out. Secured pages won't be retained in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to caching the page. You can easily prevent this if you are using **Spring Security 3.2+** using the [headers element](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#headers):

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/auth/denied" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/list" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/{userId}/edit" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/essays/main/user/delete" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <headers />

    <form-login login-page="/essays/auth/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/essays/auth/login?error=true"
                default-target-url="/essays/main/user/home"
                always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/essays/auth/denied"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/essays/auth/login"
            logout-url="/essays/auth/logout"/>
</http>
```